# How to convert rows into columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I have table with data like shown below in Oracle database.

```
emp_num  person_name  organization  earned_date  sum(hours)
-------  -----------  ------------  -----------  ----------
36372    Name1        Test1         23-MAR-11      3.17
36372    Name1        Test1         15-MAR-11      6.70
40208    Name2        Test2         08-APR-11     13.50
40208    Name2        Test2         06-APR-11     12.07
```

I need to change query output like below. How can I do that?

```
emp_num  person_name  organization  23-MAR-11  15-MAR-11  08-APR-11  06-APR-11
-------  -----------  ------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
36372     Name1       Test1           3.17        6.70      
40208     Name2       Test2                                 13.50      12.70
```

Comment: maybe this can help http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically name columns in a table, unless you use some form of dynamic SQL.  However, you can get what you want using generic date columns:

```
select emp_num, person_name, organization, 
       sum(decode(datenum, 1, hours, 0)) as date1hours,
       sum(decode(datenum, 2, hours, 0)) as date2hours,
       ...
       min(decode(datenum, 1, earned_date) as date1,
       min(decode(datenum, 2, earned_date) as date2,
       ...
from 
(
  select t.*, 
     dense_rank() over (partition by NULL order by earned_date) as datenum
  from the_table t
) t
group by emp_num, person_name, organization
```

By the way, Oracle 10g supports the `CASE` syntax, and I would advise you to use that instead of `decode`.

Comment: Could you please help me on that using case syntax

Comment: how can i possibly transpose my rows into columns by case
i have used case several time before like 
select 
id,
case when name is not null then name else 'N/A' end 
from table
but its of no use in pivot or transposing i think.

Comment: @KhurramZulfiqarAli . . . You are not the original OP.  I would suggest that you ask a question specific to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  emp_num,
  person_name,
  organization,
  sum(decode(earned_date,to_date('23/03/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),hours,0)) 23mar11,
  sum(decode(earned_date,to_date('15/03/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),hours,0)) 15mar11,
  sum(decode(earned_date,to_date('08/04/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),hours,0)) 08apr11,
  sum(decode(earned_date,to_date('06/04/2011','dd/mm/yyyy'),hours,0)) 06apr11
from
  the_table //don't know the name
group by
  emp_num,
  person_name,
  organization
```

Always use the to_date function to compare dates to strings, I have used a common UK format here.

Comment: Thanks, I given just example records. I need dynamic columns i dont know what are dates in table data.it should automatically build coulmns as pe dates